# I want to set each lines of output as a single variable?

Tags: bash

Command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep -Ei 'model name|flags|cpu core|cache size'|sed -n '1,4p'
```

Output:

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz

cache size  : 3072 KB

cpu cores   : 2

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

I want the result like below:

```
abc=model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
xyz=cache size  : 3072 KB.
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo |
    egrep -Ei 'model name|cache size'|
    sed 's/^model name/abc=model name/g' |
    sed 's/^cache size/xyz=cache size/g'
```

will product :

```
abc=model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
xyz=cache size  : 3072 KB.
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: And when you want to have the variables `abc`and `xyz`, make sure the right hand shows quotes and source the output: `source <(cat ..../xyz="cache size"/g')`

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to assign the output of a command to a variable, use the tilde character around the variable definition:

```
abc=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep -Ei 'model name'|sed -n '1,4p'`
```

Will yield:

```
echo $abc
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
```